# Change data in intra frame of MPEG file in matlab

Tags: matlab, mpeg

I need to read a MPEG video in matlab, and change the data in the Intra frame and save it again as a new MPEG file. Can someone please suggest me a way of doing this? Is this a possible task or is this impossible to do? Please help me.. Thanks in advance

I have read a mpeg file in matlab and I separated it into frames by the below code. can you please tell me how to identify the Intra frames? I'm going to change the pixel values of that frame and I have to make a new mpeg file with those frames.

```
%%Extracting & Saving of frames from a Video file through Matlab Code%%
clc;
close all;
clear all;

mov = VideoReader('song.mpg');
opFolder = fullfile(cd, 'pics');
%if  not existing 
if ~exist(opFolder, 'dir')
  %make directory & execute as indicated in opfolder variable
  mkdir(opFolder);
end

%getting no of frames
numFrames = mov.NumberOfFrames;

%setting current status of number of frames written to zero
numFramesWritten = 0;

%for loop to traverse & process from frame '1' to 'last' frames 
for t = 1 : numFrames
  currFrame = read(mov, t);    %reading individual frames
  opBaseFileName = sprintf('%3.3d.png', t);
  opFullFileName = fullfile(opFolder, opBaseFileName);
  imwrite(currFrame, opFullFileName, 'png');   %saving as 'png' file

  %indicating the current progress of the file/frame written
  progIndication = sprintf('Wrote frame %4d of %d.', t, numFrames);
  disp(progIndication);
  numFramesWritten = numFramesWritten + 1;
end      %end of 'for' loop

progIndication = sprintf('Wrote %d frames to folder "%s"',numFramesWritten, opFolder);
disp(progIndication);
```

Comment: I have read a mpeg file in matlab and I separated it into frames by the below code. can you please tell me how to identify the Intra frames? I'm going to change the pixel values of that frame and I have to make a new mpeg file with those frames.

Comment: Thank you. Your code needs to be in the question (I have copied it there for you).

Comment: what do you call Intra frame? Do you mean a particular frame?

Comment: I have shown below my code. If you can please help me

Comment: Using `VideoReader` through MATLAB already does the decoding of the frames for you.  As such, you don't have access to intraframes or interframes.  If you want access to the raw frames, you'll need to read in the data yourself manually and parse through it using the MPEG standard.  You can't use `VideoReader` to identify intraframes.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by Intra-frame you mean I-frames. There is no way to determine whether a frame is an I, P or B-frame after it has been decoded. One has to look at the raw encoded bitstream to do this. A tool such as ffprobe can help you with this.

You can do this round-about thing if you really want to:

1. Download ffmpeg tools. It has a function or utility called ffprobe. On the system terminal, execute:

   ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v:0 song.mpg
2. This will generate a text file with information about each frame. You can do some clever text processing on this file using TEXTSCAN and look for PICT_TYPE=I and identify which frames are I-frames.
3. Use these indices to read frames using VIDEOREADER.
4. Write out these frames using VIDEOWRITER.

Hope this helps.